# How is it possible to swap linux disk contents with Win7 contents?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have used Ubuntu 13.04 for some time now and I love it!
Currently I have 2 disks in my PC:
2011 HDD with 1TB of space with Win7 on it.
2006 HDD with 150GB of space with Ubuntu 13.04 on it.
As the 2006 drive is old(and could fail any day now) I would like to have Win7 on the 160GB disk and Ubuntu on the 1TB one.
How would that be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to swap the contents of your hard drives. To do so, you will need to boot to a liveCD/USB system. Any system with GParted will do. Make sure that you have backups of any important files of BOTH disks.

Before starting it might be a good idea to read through all the steps to get a general idea of what you need to do.

Boot the live distribution, run GParted and follow these steps:

1. Shrink the size of the windows partition to a size that can be accommodated by your old drive ( check the disk size and make it a couple of MB smaller just to be on the safe side)
2. Now move the partition you shrank in the previous step all the way to the right. Note1: Don't combine steps 1 and 2. It sounds counter-intuitive but its faster and safer to first re-size shrinking to the left and then move to the right rather than to shrink the partition "towards" the right side of the disk in one step.
3. Copy the linux partition(s) from your old disk to the new one. Technically speaking you don't have to copy the swap partition, just creating one of equal size on the new disk will suffice, BUT my advice is to just copy the damn thing from the old drive to the new one. This will preserve the partition UUID so you won't have to go in and make manual changes to your fstab later. Note2: If you have a separate partition for your /home folder (always a good idea) then copy it last, so it will be the rightmost linux partition. If you only have one linux partition that contains everything, then put the swap partition first and the linux partition second. This will come in handy later when resizing it.
4. Now is a good time for some testing. If you want you can disconnect or mark as hidden the old drive and the moved windows partition. Open a terminal and install GRUB on your new disk. Assuming your disk is /dev/sdb, you would need something like `grub-install /dev/sdb` If all is well your system will boot to linux. Now you can continue.
5. Shut-down, reconnect the drive if you have disconnected it, and reboot to the liveCD/USB. Run GParted again and delete all partitions from your old disk.
6. Copy the windows partition from your new disk to the old disk. Remember to un-hide it if it is hidden. Keep the "old" windows partition in the new drive hidden for the time being.
7. Time to test again. Run again the grub-install script so it can detect the windows installation. Reboot and try both windows and Ubuntu. If all is well, continue to next step.
8. You are almost done. Now you can delete the "old" windows partition from the new disk and re-size your linux partition to cover the remaining unallocated space of your new 1TB drive.

Answer (score 0):

As windows cannot read ext4 file system you need to have a utility called as ext2explore in windows to copy contents from linux to windows. From windows to linux is straightforward as linux knows how to read ntfs file system.

link for ext2explore:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2Read%20ver%202.0/ext2explore%202.0%20beta/

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous, so you should make a backup and be ready to reinstall the OS'.

You can move/copy partitions with gparted. (it technically creates a new partition) However, in order to change the partition of the device where Ubuntu is installed, you need either another device where Ubuntu (or any Unix where gparted is available) is installed or a live medium. However, deleting and copying (swapping) the partitions comprising the whole resp. devices, would probably fail. For this, you either need a third device or you could maybe first try to reduce the size of the partitions so either device could hold both at the same time.

Alternatively, you could make dd images. (First shrink the 1 TB partition with gparted to 150 GB) Assuming /dev/sdb1 (1 TB) and /dev/sdc1 (150 GB) should be replaced (creating image files WIN-2013.dd (now on 1 TB device) and UBU-2013.dd (now 150 GB)):

```
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ umount /dev/sdc1
$ dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=WIN-2013.dd
$ dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=UBU-2013.dd
```

Then create and format new empty partitions in the desired order using gparted (or any other partition manager you like) and (to interchange sdb1 and sdc1)

```
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ umount /dev/sdc1
$ dd if=UBU-2013.dd of=/dev/sdb1
$ dd if=WIN-2013.dd of=/dev/sdc1
```

Either ways, you'll probably need to update-grub. First mount the ubuntu partition while you're still in the live or third linux installation and

```
$ cd /media/THE_ROOT_OF_THAT_NEW_UBUNTU
$ sudo mount -o bind /dev ./dev
$ sudo mount -o bind /sys ./sys
$ sudo mount -t proc /proc ./proc
$ chroot .
```

then your name@machine should have changed, so go:

```
$ update-grub
```

(However, I don't know what to do with Windows if not installing a dummy linux just for grub boot!)